# How to display my data with categories in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem for display my data in table

[Example in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/orKMRchsghGVEG5V2ABk)

I want to initialise my table with another table

```
 $scope.groups = [
                    { name: 'Employees',
                        members: [
                            data
                        ]
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `[]`:

```
members: data
```

#### [Updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iIeZbOmZwtwsySSHjeX3?p=preview)

---

Because data is actually an array of javascript objects and in your code you were wrapping the array in another array like this:

```
 members: [ 
            [{},{}...] 
          ]
```